# How to make a loop structure out of an array in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I tried that but it doesn't work.

```
create function test (_values int[])
  returns void as $$
begin

  for _v in _values
  loop
    ...
  end loop;

end;
$$
  language plpgsql;
```